# Trying to get nyan reporter working with gulp jshint

Tags: javascript, gulp

Trying to get gulp-mocha to run mocha test on JavaScript files and return the result using nyan cat reporter. When I run the command I get the following error

```
'mocha' errored after 244 ms
ReferenceError in plugin 'gulp-mocha'
Message:
    document is not defined
```

Here is the task in my Gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require ('gulp-mocha');

    gulp.task('mocha', function () {
        return gulp.src(jsSources, {read: false})
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'nyan'}));

    });
```

Do I need to install the 'nayn' reporter as a dependency also?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to install it as a dependency. Try this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch(['./mocha/*'], ['mocha']);
});

gulp.task('mocha', function(){
    return gulp.src('./mocha/*', {read: true})
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'nyan'}));
});
```